# block list for cache initialization

Tags: .net, async-await, locking, .net-core

I have IHostedService implementation which reads files from the web each 10 seconds which build sort of cache.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    while (true)
    {            
      if (await _reader.ExpiredAsync())
      {
        var package = await _reader.GetAsync();
        _packageRepository.Add(package);
      }
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), cancellationToken);
    }
  }
}
```

My repository reinitialize '_files' each time as I fully rebuild the cache if it's expired.

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
public void Add(Package package)
{
  _cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
  try
  {
    _files = new List<FilesOfSomekind>(package.Files);
  }
  finally
  {   
    _cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
  }
}

private List<FilesOfSomekind> Read()
{
  _cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
  try
  {
    return _files;
  }
  finally
  {
    _cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
  }
}
```

My problem is with initial call, when there is nothing in '_files', it may take few seconds before the cache is build and i want to block access to Read().

**Any way to solve that ?**

Comment: Well you could set an initialized flag. But I think a better solution would be just to initialize `_files` to an `Enumerable.Empty<T>` and let the readers see the empty cache until it's built/rebuilt, you'd need another local in your `Add` that builds the cache before setting `_files`. Would that solution work in your context?

Comment: @JSteward, i want reader blocked ( wait ) until cache is build.